# text not centering right under the image with border

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a list of story like on instagram. But i have a little problem with the text under the profile-image that is rounded (in circle).
How can I center the text? I've tried with 'text-align: center;' but is not working, you can see above..

How can I fix this problem?

Btw, use the snippet code on 'fullscreen' to see correctly.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cairo:wght@200;300;400;600;700;900&display=swap);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Signika:wght@300&display=swap);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap);

:root {
    --main-color: #4D6275;
    --second-color: #3F5060;

    --body-bg: #2E3841;
    --box-bg: #272F37;

    --text-color: #D5D5D5;
    --grey-color: #B2B2B2;
    --simple-color: #C3C3C3;

    --color-blue: #008080;
    --color-red: #9C4646;

    --content-height: 92px;
    --space-top: 30px;
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: rgba(var(--b3f,250,250,250),1);
    color: var(--text-color);
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

input:focus {
    outline: none;
}


.content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    max-width: 614px;
    width: 100%;
}

.stories {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border: 1px solid rgba(var(--b6a,219,219,219),1);
    border-radius: 2.5px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 110px;
}

.stories-items {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.btn-type-story {
    border: none;
    background: unset;
    color: unset;
    outline: none;
}

.story-img {
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 56px;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-border-radius: 56px;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    border-radius: 56px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    float: left;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;

    display: block;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px lightgray;
}

.active .story-img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #2EB14D;
}

.story-name {
    color: rgba(var(--f52,142,142,142),1);
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    max-width: 64px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    top: 110px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.active .story-name {
    color: rgba(var(--i1d,38,38,38),1);
}

.s-item:first-child {
    margin-left: 13px;
}

.s-item {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div class="content">
    <div class="stories">
        <div class="stories-items">
            <div class="s-item active">
                <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1157313327867092993/a09TxL_1_400x400.jpg')"></div>
                    <div class="story-name">
                        cristiano
                    </div>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="s-item active">
                <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://www.fcbarcelonanoticias.com/uploads/s1/12/04/53/6/neymar-viaje.jpeg')"></div>
                    <div class="story-name">
                        Neymar
                    </div>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="s-item active">
                <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://www.gds.ro/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/messi.jpg')"></div>
                    <div class="story-name">
                        messi
                    </div>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="s-item active">
                <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://www.prosport.ro/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Kylian-Mbappe-6-scaled.jpg')"></div>
                    <div class="story-name">
                        Mbappe
                    </div>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="s-item">
                <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://s.hs-data.com/bilder/spieler/gross/19198.jpg')"></div>
                    <div class="story-name">
                        sr4
                    </div>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="s-item">
                <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://bayernstrikes.com/wp-content/uploads/getty-images/2017/07/1233654260.jpeg')"></div>
                    <div class="story-name">
                        Joshua
                    </div>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="s-item">
                <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/FRA-ARG_%2811%29_-_Paul_Pogba_%28cropped_2%29.jpg')"></div>
                    <div class="story-name">
                        Pogba
                    </div>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="s-item">
                <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://cacheimg.gsp.ro/autocrop/smp-images-production/gsp.ro/30012021/1611999491716.jpg?width=848&height=0')"></div>
                    <div class="story-name">
                        Rashford
                    </div>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: div inside a button is an invalid HTML markup that will not pass a [Markup Validator](https://validator.w3.org/)! Also why use a div and a background image instead of an `<img>` tag? Neither `background-clip` nor `border-radius` require a prefix. They are supported by all browsers per default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set width same image above i.e `width: 56px;`

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cairo:wght@200;300;400;600;700;900&display=swap);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Signika:wght@300&display=swap);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap);
:root {
  --main-color: #4D6275;
  --second-color: #3F5060;
  --body-bg: #2E3841;
  --box-bg: #272F37;
  --text-color: #D5D5D5;
  --grey-color: #B2B2B2;
  --simple-color: #C3C3C3;
  --color-blue: #008080;
  --color-red: #9C4646;
  --content-height: 92px;
  --space-top: 30px;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: rgba(var(--b3f, 250, 250, 250), 1);
  color: var(--text-color);
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  max-width: 614px;
  width: 100%;
}

.stories {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid rgba(var(--b6a, 219, 219, 219), 1);
  border-radius: 2.5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
}

.stories-items {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.btn-type-story {
  border: none;
  background: unset;
  color: unset;
  outline: none;
}

.story-img {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 56px;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-border-radius: 56px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  border-radius: 56px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  float: left;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px lightgray;
}

.active .story-img {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #2EB14D;
}

.story-name {
  color: rgba(var(--f52, 142, 142, 142), 1);
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
  width: 56px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  top: 110px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.active .story-name {
  color: rgba(var(--i1d, 38, 38, 38), 1);
}

.s-item:first-child {
  margin-left: 13px;
}

.s-item {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="stories">
      <div class="stories-items">
        <div class="s-item active">
          <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1157313327867092993/a09TxL_1_400x400.jpg')"></div>
                    <div class="story-name">
                        cristiano
                    </div>
                </button>
        </div>
        <div class="s-item active">
          <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://www.fcbarcelonanoticias.com/uploads/s1/12/04/53/6/neymar-viaje.jpeg')"></div>
                    <div class="story-name">
                        Neymar
                    </div>
                </button>
        </div>
        <div class="s-item active">
          <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://www.gds.ro/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/messi.jpg')"></div>
                    <div class="story-name">
                        messi
                    </div>
                </button>
        </div>
        <div class="s-item active">
          <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://www.prosport.ro/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Kylian-Mbappe-6-scaled.jpg')"></div>
                    <div class="story-name">
                        Mbappe
                    </div>
                </button>
        </div>
        <div class="s-item">
          <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://s.hs-data.com/bilder/spieler/gross/19198.jpg')"></div>
                    <div class="story-name">
                        sr4
                    </div>
                </button>
        </div>
        <div class="s-item">
          <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://bayernstrikes.com/wp-content/uploads/getty-images/2017/07/1233654260.jpeg')"></div>
                    <div class="story-name">
                        Joshua
                    </div>
                </button>
        </div>
        <div class="s-item">
          <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/FRA-ARG_%2811%29_-_Paul_Pogba_%28cropped_2%29.jpg')"></div>
                    <div class="story-name">
                        Pogba
                    </div>
                </button>
        </div>
        <div class="s-item">
          <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://cacheimg.gsp.ro/autocrop/smp-images-production/gsp.ro/30012021/1611999491716.jpg?width=848&height=0')"></div>
                    <div class="story-name">
                        Rashford
                    </div>
                </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you! is working now. Thank you soo much!

Answer (score 1):

On the container write

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cairo:wght@200;300;400;600;700;900&display=swap);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Signika:wght@300&display=swap);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap);

:root {
    --main-color: #4D6275;
    --second-color: #3F5060;

    --body-bg: #2E3841;
    --box-bg: #272F37;

    --text-color: #D5D5D5;
    --grey-color: #B2B2B2;
    --simple-color: #C3C3C3;

    --color-blue: #008080;
    --color-red: #9C4646;

    --content-height: 92px;
    --space-top: 30px;
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: rgba(var(--b3f,250,250,250),1);
    color: var(--text-color);
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

input:focus {
    outline: none;
}


.content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    max-width: 614px;
    width: 100%;
}

.stories {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border: 1px solid rgba(var(--b6a,219,219,219),1);
    border-radius: 2.5px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 110px;
}

.stories-items {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.btn-type-story {
    border: none;
    background: unset;
    color: unset;
    outline: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.story-img {
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 56px;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-border-radius: 56px;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    border-radius: 56px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    float: left;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;

    display: block;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px lightgray;
}

.active .story-img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #2EB14D;
}

.story-name {
    color: rgba(var(--f52,142,142,142),1);
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    max-width: 64px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    top: 110px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.active .story-name {
    color: rgba(var(--i1d,38,38,38),1);
}

.s-item:first-child {
    margin-left: 13px;
}

.s-item {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div class="content">
    <div class="stories">
        <div class="stories-items">
            <div class="s-item active">
                <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1157313327867092993/a09TxL_1_400x400.jpg')"></div>
                    <div class="story-name">
                        cristiano
                    </div>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="s-item active">
                <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://www.fcbarcelonanoticias.com/uploads/s1/12/04/53/6/neymar-viaje.jpeg')"></div>
                    <span class="story-name">
                        Neymar
                    </span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="s-item active">
                <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://www.gds.ro/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/messi.jpg')"></div>
                    <div class="story-name">
                        messi
                    </div>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="s-item active">
                <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://www.prosport.ro/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Kylian-Mbappe-6-scaled.jpg')"></div>
                    <div class="story-name">
                        Mbappe
                    </div>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="s-item">
                <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://s.hs-data.com/bilder/spieler/gross/19198.jpg')"></div>
                    <div class="story-name">
                        sr4
                    </div>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="s-item">
                <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://bayernstrikes.com/wp-content/uploads/getty-images/2017/07/1233654260.jpeg')"></div>
                    <div class="story-name">
                        Joshua
                    </div>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="s-item">
                <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/FRA-ARG_%2811%29_-_Paul_Pogba_%28cropped_2%29.jpg')"></div>
                    <div class="story-name">
                        Pogba
                    </div>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="s-item">
                <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://cacheimg.gsp.ro/autocrop/smp-images-production/gsp.ro/30012021/1611999491716.jpg?width=848&height=0')"></div>
                    <div class="story-name">
                        Rashford
                    </div>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hei, you can try using

```
.story-name {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

and remove the `text-align:center` property

Comment: Try the margin solution with ```width: 100%```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this class

```
.active .story-name{
width:100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cairo:wght@200;300;400;600;700;900&display=swap);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Signika:wght@300&display=swap);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap);

:root {
    --main-color: #4D6275;
    --second-color: #3F5060;

    --body-bg: #2E3841;
    --box-bg: #272F37;

    --text-color: #D5D5D5;
    --grey-color: #B2B2B2;
    --simple-color: #C3C3C3;

    --color-blue: #008080;
    --color-red: #9C4646;

    --content-height: 92px;
    --space-top: 30px;
}

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: rgba(var(--b3f,250,250,250),1);
    color: var(--text-color);
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

input:focus {
    outline: none;
}


.content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    max-width: 614px;
    width: 100%;
}

.stories {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border: 1px solid rgba(var(--b6a,219,219,219),1);
    border-radius: 2.5px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 110px;
}

.stories-items {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.btn-type-story {
    border: none;
    background: unset;
    color: unset;
    outline: none;
}

.story-img {
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 56px;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-border-radius: 56px;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    border-radius: 56px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    float: left;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;

    display: block;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px lightgray;
}

.active .story-img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #2EB14D;
}

.story-name {
    color: rgba(var(--f52,142,142,142),1);
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    max-width: 64px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    top: 110px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}

.active .story-name {
    color: rgba(var(--i1d,38,38,38),1);
}

.s-item:first-child {
    margin-left: 13px;
}

.s-item {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="stories">
      <div class="stories-items">
          <div class="s-item active">
              <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                  <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1157313327867092993/a09TxL_1_400x400.jpg')"></div>
                  <div class="story-name">
                      cristiano
                  </div>
              </button>
          </div>
          <div class="s-item active">
              <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                  <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://www.fcbarcelonanoticias.com/uploads/s1/12/04/53/6/neymar-viaje.jpeg')"></div>
                  <div class="story-name">
                      Neymar
                  </div>
              </button>
          </div>
          <div class="s-item active">
              <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                  <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://www.gds.ro/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/messi.jpg')"></div>
                  <div class="story-name">
                      messi
                  </div>
              </button>
          </div>
          <div class="s-item active">
              <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                  <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://www.prosport.ro/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Kylian-Mbappe-6-scaled.jpg')"></div>
                  <div class="story-name">
                      Mbappe
                  </div>
              </button>
          </div>
          <div class="s-item">
              <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                  <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://s.hs-data.com/bilder/spieler/gross/19198.jpg')"></div>
                  <div class="story-name">
                      sr4
                  </div>
              </button>
          </div>
          <div class="s-item">
              <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                  <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://bayernstrikes.com/wp-content/uploads/getty-images/2017/07/1233654260.jpeg')"></div>
                  <div class="story-name">
                      Joshua
                  </div>
              </button>
          </div>
          <div class="s-item">
              <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                  <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/FRA-ARG_%2811%29_-_Paul_Pogba_%28cropped_2%29.jpg')"></div>
                  <div class="story-name">
                      Pogba
                  </div>
              </button>
          </div>
          <div class="s-item">
              <button class="btn-type-story" aria-label="Neymar story" tabindex="0">
                  <div class="story-img" style="background-image: url('https://cacheimg.gsp.ro/autocrop/smp-images-production/gsp.ro/30012021/1611999491716.jpg?width=848&height=0')"></div>
                  <div class="story-name">
                      Rashford
                  </div>
              </button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add width: 100% to your class "story-name"